# FilterException when creating an EthFilter in web3j

Tags: events, web3j, filters

I'm using **web3j** to create a filter to listen to events.

Specifically, I want to listen to events of a specific contract between a certain block number and now.

This is my code:

```
Web3j web3j = ...
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(Numeric.toBigInt("3306085")), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddr);
web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(log -> onNewEvent(log));
```

However, when I run that code, I get the following error message:

**FilterException: Invalid request: One of the blocks specified in filter (fromBlock, toBlock or blockHash) cannot be found.**

The stack trace looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | Invalid request: One of the blocks specified in filter (fromBlock, toBlock or blockHash) cannot be found.
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate$BaseEmitter.error(FlowableCreate.java:292)
    [...]
Caused by: org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.FilterException: Invalid request: One of the blocks specified in filter (fromBlock, toBlock or blockHash) cannot be found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue is that Numeric.toBigInt("") expects the block number to be in **hex format** not in decimal format.
So, either pass the block number as hex string or immediately create a BigInteger if your block number string is in decimal format.

Changing the code to this works for me:

```
Web3j web3j = ...
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(new BigInteger("3306085")), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddr);
web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(log -> onNewEvent(log));
```